# Unable to install Vagrant + VirtualBox on MacOSX

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am using MacOSX High Sierra.

I have installed Virtual Box using VirtualBox-5.2.10-122088-OSX.dmg
and Vagrant using vagrant_2.0.4_x86_64

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise64
```

> A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
>   ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
>   the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
>   `vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

```
vagrant up
```

> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>
> ==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
>
> ```
> default: Box Provider: virtualbox
>
> default: Box Version: >= 0
> ```
>
> ==> default: Loading metadata for box 'hashicorp/precise64'
>
> ```
> default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/precise64
> ```
>
> ==> default: Adding box 'hashicorp/precise64' (v1.1.0) for provider: virtualbox
>
> ```
> default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise64/versions/1.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
>
> default: Download redirected to host: hashicorp-files.hashicorp.com
> ```
>
> ==> default: Successfully added box 'hashicorp/precise64' (v1.1.0) for 'virtualbox'!
>
> ==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise64'...
>
> ==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
>
> ==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
>
> ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant2_default_1524679963169_18025
>
> ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
>
> ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
>
> ```
> default: Adapter 1: nat
> ```
>
> ==> default: Forwarding ports...
>
> ```
> default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
> ```
>
> ==> default: Booting VM...
>
> There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["startvm", "88aa0471-2f7b-4c84-b06b-2f2014cb3ae0", "--type", "headless"]
>
> Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'vagrant2_default_1524679963169_18025' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1)
>
> VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine

Elsewhere I read that I should have been using a wrong binary but I have downloaded the MacOSX versions of virtualbox and vagrant; cant use any other!

I was following instructions from https://www.sitepoint.com/re-introducing-vagrant-right-way-start-php/. As I understand it, I don't need to install any OS as vagrant would do that anyway.

But looks like they are incomplete or something is missing, or are they?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can get more details by running

```
vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
```

Most likely using a version of virtual box that your current vagrant installation doesn't support.